# Find all except the two most recent versions with different major version

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, zsh

**Background:**

I want to delete folders of iOS device support files which are not needed but take a lot of disk space. I want to keep only the two most recent versions which have a different major version (12.2.1 and 13.0.1 including their arm64 versions).

Is this possible using a shell one liner?

**Given a list of folders named using semantic versioning like the following:**

```
11.2.1
11.2.1 arm64
12.0.1
12.0.1 arm64
12.0.2
12.0.2 arm64
12.1.1
12.1.1 arm64
12.1.2
12.1.2 arm64
12.2.1
12.2.1 arm64
13.0.0
13.0.0 arm64
13.0.1
13.0.1 arm64
```

**Expected output:**

```
11.2.1
11.2.1 arm64
12.0.1
12.0.1 arm64
12.0.2
12.0.2 arm64
12.1.1
12.1.1 arm64
12.1.2
12.1.2 arm64
13.0.0
13.0.0 arm64
```

**Means this should be stripped from the original list:**

```
12.2.1
12.2.1 arm64
13.0.1
13.0.1 arm64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each version has both vanilla version and arm64 version, how about:

```
comm -2 -3 list.txt <(sort -t. -n -r list.txt | awk -F. 'a[$1]++<2' | head -4 | sort)
```

where `list.txt` holds:

```
11.2.1
11.2.1 arm64
12.0.1
12.0.1 arm64
12.0.2
12.0.2 arm64
12.1.1
12.1.1 arm64
12.1.2
12.1.2 arm64
12.2.1
12.2.1 arm64
13.0.0
13.0.0 arm64
13.0.1
13.0.1 arm64
```

and the output:

```
11.2.1
11.2.1 arm64
12.0.1
12.0.1 arm64
12.0.2
12.0.2 arm64
12.1.1
12.1.1 arm64
12.1.2
12.1.2 arm64
13.0.0
13.0.0 arm64
```

Comment: WOW! That already comes very close to what I want... Thanks so far! Is there a way to base the script just on the version numbers and ignore the arm64 (or whatever) suffix of the folder name?

Could you explain whats going on there a little bit in your answer? So I can make some comments on my script!

Comment: what do you think about this: `FOLDERS=$(ls -vd ${HOME}/Desktop/Versions/*/ | sed 's/.$//')
KEEP=$(printf "%s\n" "$(IFS=\n; echo "${FOLDERS[*]}")" |sort -t. -nr | awk -F. 'a[$1]++<1' | cut -d' ' -f1 | head -2 | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/.$//')
REMOVE=$(printf "%s\n" "$(IFS=\n; echo "${FOLDERS[*]}")" | grep -vE $KEEP)
printf "%s\n" "$(IFS=\n; echo "${REMOVE[*]}")"`? Imagin FOLDERS=$(cat list.txt)

Comment: I suppose your script is okay so far. Both yours and mine are based on
the same logic and algorithm. In a detail, some fuddy-duddies may comment
that you should not use uppercase as a variable name or you should not
parse the output of `ls`. You will get learned about "bash pitfalls". BR.